# GatsbyJS Typography plugin's css gets overwritten

Tags: gatsby, antd, typography

I have a GatsbyJS app with TypographyJS (via Gatsby plugin) with Ant Design UI framework. The typography plugin is added following the official documentation, [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-three/)

To make ant design CSS work you have to import the ant design css in the `gatsby-browser.js` file according to their documentation, [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce)

The ant design css overwrites the typography-plugin styles. **I want to use the ant design styling with the typography for fonts etc.**

#### gatsby-browser.js

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Browser APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/
 */

// You can delete this file if you're not using it
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
```

#### typography.js

```
import Typography from "typography"
import fairyGateTheme from "typography-theme-fairy-gates"

/**
 * Issue:
 * Fairy Gates Theme: Messed up text shadow in default starter project header
 * 
 * Solution:
 * https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typography.js/issues/155#issuecomment-490715480
 */
fairyGateTheme.overrideThemeStyles = () => ({
  a: {
    textShadow: `none`,
    backgroundImage: `none`,
  },
});

const typography = new Typography(fairyGateTheme)

export const { scale, rhythm, options } = typography
export default typography
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(